# How to set state-highlight on primefaces wizard

Tags: primefaces

I wonder how it is possible to change default behavior of primefaces wizard

```
<p:wizard />
```

I mean that after user click next button the highlighted step (tab) are only current step. Not steps which are before him. In my implementation of primefaces wizzard I would get the behavior which will paint steps which are before current step. To do that I need only add class 'ui-state-highlight' to tabs precending current tab. Of course mechanism should works when user click back button

I have tried use 'onnext' and 'onback' client side events but without result. This events are executed before next step are rendered. In effect that was change by function onnext and onback are overwritten by primefaces scirpt.

Could somebody help with this issue? I will grateful for help

[image]

Comment: This component has ajax event handlers. `oncomplete` of those you can fire any javascript you like, including using some jquery to finding the active tab and add class to the tabs before them. Another option is to download the source of the component, adapt it and have it highlight more.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

We need to override the **loadStep** function of **PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype**

I changed oryginal piece of code

from

```
//update step status
if($this.cfg.showStepStatus) {
   $this.stepControls.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   $($this.stepControls.get(currentStepIndex)).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
}
```

to

```
//update step status
if ($this.cfg.showStepStatus) {
   var stepsCon = $this.stepControls;
   stepsCon.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   stepsCon.each(function (index) {
       if (currentStepIndex >= index) {
           $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
       }
   });
}
```

and it start works as I expect.

all javascript override looks like

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Wizard.prototype.loadStep = function (stepToGo, isBack) {
var $this = this,
        options = {
            source: this.id,
            process: this.id,
            update: this.id,
            formId: this.cfg.formId,
            params: [
                {name: this.id + '_wizardRequest', value: true},
                {name: this.id + '_stepToGo', value: stepToGo}
            ],
            onsuccess: function (responseXML, status, xhr) {
                PrimeFaces.ajax.Response.handle(responseXML, status, xhr, {
                    widget: $this,
                    handle: function (content) {
                        this.content.html(content);
                    }
                });

                return true;
            },
            oncomplete: function (xhr, status, args) {
                $this.currentStep = args.currentStep;

                if (!args.validationFailed) {
                    var currentStepIndex = $this.getStepIndex($this.currentStep);

                    if ($this.cfg.showNavBar) {
                        if (currentStepIndex === $this.cfg.steps.length - 1) {
                            $this.hideNextNav();
                            $this.showBackNav();
                        } else if (currentStepIndex === 0) {
                            $this.hideBackNav();
                            $this.showNextNav();
                        } else {
                            $this.showBackNav();
                            $this.showNextNav();
                        }
                    }

                    //update step status
                    if ($this.cfg.showStepStatus) {
                        var stepsCon = $this.stepControls;
                        stepsCon.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                        stepsCon.each(function (index) {
                            if (currentStepIndex >= index) {
                                $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (isBack) {
           options.params.push({name: this.id + '_backRequest', value: true});
        }

        PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.handle(options);
};
```